# Programa para la facultad. No le encuentro errores al código. no se que podrá ser. este mismo archivo tiene mas funciones que si andan. Gracias

Tags: javascript, string, function

Las indicaciones para el programa están en comentarios en el código, no se porque no anda, no le encuentro errores en el código y además tengo mas funciones en el archivo que si andan. Ojala puedan ayudarme a encontrar una solución. Gracias
Dejo el código y el output del mismo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido(a) a SOes. El código no debería mostrarse a través de imágenes, recuerda que no todos podemos verlo. Te invito a que [edites](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/561970/edit) tu pregunta y pongas el código con su respectivo formato. Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tengas respuestas cuanto antes.

Comment: Buenas noches Pablo, te sugiero leer [ask].
Lo ideal sería que subas el código no imágenes, en general se pide lo que se conoce como mínimo código verificable, esto permite poder realizar las pruebas pertinentes para poder ayudarte en el menor tiempo posible.

Comment: Te sugiero que cojas el código y lo pegues en la pregunta como texto, las imágenes de código no sirven para motivarnos a ayudarte pues tenemos que teclearlo entero para ayudarte, con los posibles gazapos que podamos cometer al hacerlo, y eso requiere demasiado tiempo. Por otra parte, también te sugiero que lo pegues y ejecutes en https://jsfiddle.net para que lo depures tu mismo y veas si funciona o no (que es lo que haré yo justo cuando lo pongas aquí en modo texto para darte una respuesta).

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.